# Crack AES ECB mode C++

Tags: encryption, aes, decryption, c++

I have this little piece of code for encrypting:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

int encrypt(char *filename) {

    byte key[ 16 ];
    int i;
    memset( key, 0x00, 16);

    for(i=0;i<=sizeof(*key);i++){ 
    key[i]=(byte)(std::rand() % 256);
    }

    auto enc = new ECB_Mode<AES>::Encryption(key, sizeof(key));
}
```

Is there a method to crack or decrypt a piece of encrypted text encrypted with this function?

Comment: Why is `filename` not used inside the `encrypt` function? Please, provide the entire function

Comment: Assuming this code were changed to actually encrypt 'a piece of text', the biggest problem is you set only 2 bytes of key, which is very easy to bruteforce even without cracking the probably-weak RNG per akg answer. Conversely if you had coded what you apparently intended, it would have an overrun possibly leading to destroying your data. If you want to program security-critical code in C++, a good start would be programing in C++ correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is that you use a standard random function instead of a cryptographic random. I don't see how you seeded that, but if it is `srand(time(0))` then it can probably be cracked.

However AES ECB mode is still AES. If you have only 1 block of ciphertext it is ok. If you have lots of texts then probably one will still be unable to crack it, the problem with ECB mode is that 2 blocks of the same plaintext will have the same ciphertext block too. So it really depends on the text you want to encrypt and the attacker's knowledge of the original plaintext. What you see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) is a picture encoded where there are lots of similar blocks. All the white blocks will be similar, all the black blocks will be similar and so on and so forth.

Comment: This is trivially cracked if an attacker can inject contents for you to encrypt before something sensitive.

Comment: If you are referring to a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack - to which AES is resistant, no you can't derive the key thus can't crack the other unknown parts. Could you elaborate?

Comment: ECB is *not* resistant to an [adaptive chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack). Imagine Alice has a block of sensitive data, and Eve can inject her own plaintext before it gets encrypted. Eve gets Alice to encrypt a block of 31 NULs followed by a NUL, followed by the secret data. Repeat with 32 NULs followed by `\x01`. Repeatd, followed by `\x02`. Repeat for all until `\xff`. Now Eve has a lookup table for every possible value of the last byte. Ask Alice to encrypt 31 NULs, followed by the secret data.

Comment: The last byte of the block will be the first byte of the secret data. And it will be one of the 256 values you have a lookup table for. Repeat until you have an entire block of data.

Comment: Yes, that attack exists, but doesn't apply for this scenario. You need an oracle for that to work. Technically you are right (iff you can inject content before the plaintext), because 1 byte of the plaintext can still be decrypted and that is a piece of the data, but practically infeasible.

Comment: Who says it doesn't apply in this scenario? This code doesn't necessarily exist in a complete vacuum. I explicitly prefixed my comment with the disclaimer that this attack applies if an attacker can inject plantexts, which is inarguably true. "Probably one will still be unable to crack it" is flat-out incorrect under an adaptive chosen-plaintext attack model which are *common* in practice. Additionally, this attack allows the decryption of effectively the full ciphertext after the injectable plaintext — it's not limited to a single byte.

Comment: You wrote inject contents before something sensitive. This only allows a single byte. For a complete crack you need lots of rounds and/or injecting N bytes after each ciphertext bytes. If  you paid attention you saw that the key is freshly random generated in the function, so that excludes option one. But yes, that's right the context is not clear, though the sentence is still correct, I used 'probably'.